# Evaluating a limit in the space of distributions

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

Evaluate the following limit in $\mathbb{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$:
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \, \frac{e^{\frac{i |x|^2}{4 \varepsilon}}}{(4 \pi \varepsilon)^{\frac{n}{2}}}$$
where $|x|$ is the Euclidean norm of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I was dealing with this limit because it was left as an exercise from the book, but i have no clue on how to solve it.
As an hint, the book suggests to start with $n=1$, so i tried to solve it using the lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem but i can't still find the correct answer.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

(for $n=1$) let $$F_\varepsilon(x)=\int_0^{\varepsilon^{-1/2} x} \frac{e^{i y^2/4}}{(4\pi)^{1/2}}dy$$
The main point is that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} F_\varepsilon(x) =sign(x) C $$ converges (the integral is some kind of alternated series). Whence $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}F_\varepsilon=sign(x) C$$  in the sense of distributions, from which $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \, \frac{e^{i x^2/(4 \varepsilon)}}{(4 \pi \varepsilon)^{1/2}}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}F_\varepsilon'=(sign(x) C)'=2\delta(x) C$$ in the sense of distributions.

To find $C$: $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx = \frac12\sqrt{\pi}$ gives $\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2 x^2}dx = \frac1{2a}\sqrt{\pi}$. By analytic continuation it stays true for $a\in \Bbb{C}^*,\Re(a)\ge 0$ so that $C=\frac12 e^{i\pi/4}$.